# More than 2 Cname pointing to one URL

Tags: cname

I need to perform a dry run on Cname changes before go live. We already have existing website and would like to use the same domain name.

Is it possible to have more than 2 CNAMEs point to one URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but I think for SEO reasons it is not a good idea. 
Better would be:
`URL:xyz`
Primary website: `AA CNAME XY`
Second site: `BB redirect 301 to AA`